# Cant install signed apk in real device (Ionic cordova)

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have developed an app which is ready to launch on play store.I have signed the app as ionic app publishing documents said.When my signed apk was ready i copied the apk to my device and tried installing it but, it says 'You cant install this application'.I dont have any previous apk installed on my device.I have tried opening the signed apk in android studio and tried installing it from their, it worked.I just want a confirmation that should i upload this apk to playstore or do i need to find the bug.

[I followed these steps](https://ionicframework.com/docs/deployment/play-store#signing-an-apk)

Comment: you could try uploading it and google play will check your apk as well, then assign it to safe internal "track" (Closed Alpha) - and test it this way.

Comment: can you please share some links so that i can get any idea about `safe internal tracks`

Comment: yeah follow the "creating closed track": https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213#create_additional_track